# How to search content of formula in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheet, if you use formulas in one cell, it seems it cannot be found by filtering with content. I think the reason is that google sheet don't think it is a text cell. Then how can I search or filter based on the content of the formula. For example,
I have several cells which value is:

=IMAGE("https://-----.googleusercontent.com/-----------------")

I cannot search it by string or text like "googleusercontent". How can I filter or search this cell? Thank you very much.

Comment: Beware of pasting unknown content into your spreadsheet

Comment: How about [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)?

Comment: @Cooper Thank you. I agree. I will update the content in my post.

Comment: If I understand it right. What you suggest is to add a new column with "getFormula()". Then filter with new column. Am I right? However, it is not suitable if the sheet cannot be edited.

Comment: What I suggest is that you research getFormula and figure out what you need to do on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the `Find and Replace` dialog (press `Ctrl+H`) and check `Also search within Formulas`:

[image]

You will see the cells with formulas unwrap as this option is checked.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it worked only in "find" way. It didn't support "filter" way.